# overriding findResource

Tags: java, resources, arrays, classloader

I have a custom ClassLoader and I want getResource to look for resources at a custom location.
Therefore, What I want to do is to override findResource, as I want it to return an array of bytes as the result.
The return type of the findResource function is URL.
So the question is, how do I create a URL object from a byte[] ?

I have tried this method which appeared to be invalid:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
    byte[] myByteArray = new byte[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x3};
    protected URL findResource(String name)
    {
        URL res = super.findResource(name);
        res = new URL(new String(myByteArray));
        return res;
    }
}
```

When I tried to run it I got the exception:

```
MalformedURLException: no protocol ?PNG ......
```

I understand that it thinks that the protocol is "?PNG ..." (and what comes after it), but what is the right protocol for a `byte[]`?

Comment: Where is your effort ?

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I thought it's irrelevant since it didn't work.

Comment: you should share your effort along with log trace, then someone can assist you

Comment: There is very little we can make from your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I've attached a custom URLStreamHandler to the URL during construction.  For example:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
    final byte[] myByteArray = new byte[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x3};
    protected URL findResource(String name)
    {
        URL res = super.findResource(name);
        if (res != null) {
            res = new URL(null, "my-bytes:" + name, new URLStreamHandler() {
                protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) {
                    return new URLConnection() {
                        public void connect() {}

                        public InputStream getInputStream() {
                            return new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray);
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

This is rather crude (and requires permissions if Java 2 security is enabled), so you might need a more complete URLStreamHandler implementation or you might need to globally register it with the JVM depending on the needs of the code trying to use the URL (e.g., if the caller expects to be able to serialize URLs, create new URLs by copying, get the length of the data, etc.), but something very basic like this can be useful for prototyping, debugging, or as a starting point for a more complete implementation.

Comment: in jdk7 there is no such constructor for URL, but I'll handle it

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Oops, you're right, I forgot to pass null as the context argument.  I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: I also noticed, that there is no need to append name to 'spec' parameter, I just passed protocol and seems that it was sufficient. Is it true?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Yes, appending the name is not strictly necessary, but it's very minimal effort and could make debugging easier.  (It would also be needed if you wanted to eventually add richer support.)